# Combine two array and add value of array count

Tags: php

I have two array like this

```
$arr1 = array('Prabhash', 'Nagda', 'Sayyed','Prabhash');
$arr2 = array('4', '1', '2','5');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

And I want output like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
     (
       [0] =>Prabhash
       [1] =>9
     )
[1] => => Array
     (
       [0] =>Nagda
       [1] =>1
     )
[2] => => Array
     (
       [0] =>Sayyed
       [1] =>2
     )

)
```

I have tried to combine and merge array but not success, Hope someone will help me for this better.

Comment: use array merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760606)

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('Prabhash', 'Nagda', 'Sayyed','Prabhash');
$arr2 = array('4', '1', '2','5');
$result=array();
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($result[$value]))
    {
        $result[$value][1]+=$arr2[$key];
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$value]=array($value,$arr2[$key]);
    }
}
$result=  array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prabhash
            [1] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nagda
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sayyed
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `array_map`, `array_keys`, `array_flip`, `array_unique`, `array_intersect_key` and `array_sum` functions:

```
$arr1 = array('Prabhash', 'Nagda', 'Sayyed','Prabhash');
$arr2 = array('4', '1', '2','5');

$result = array_map(function($n) use($arr1, $arr2){
    $sum = array_sum(array_intersect_key($arr2, array_flip(array_keys($arr1, $n))));
    return [$n, $sum];
}, array_unique($arr1));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prabhash
            [1] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nagda
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sayyed
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: OMG I just came back to this page to brag about this awesome one-liner I made for this question and joke about using so many functions in my solution!   AND YOU ALREADY POSTED MY EXACT CODE!!!    AAAARGGH!   (...upvote)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
<?php       
$arr1 = array('Prabhash', 'Nagda', 'Sayyed','Prabhash');
$arr2 = array('4', '1', '2','5');
$newArray = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$value][0] =$value;
    if(!isset($newArray[$value][1]) || $newArray[$value][1] == null)
        $newArray[$value][1] = $arr2[$key];
    else
        $newArray[$value][1] = $newArray[$value][1]+$arr2[$key];
}
$newArray = array_values($newArray);

echo "<pre>";   
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

OUTPUT :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prabhash
            [1] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nagda
            [1] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sayyed
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```